# Symfony routing find by id but url show name

Tags: php, symfony

I am working with Symfony2 project and there are routings like 
 `pattern:  /specialoffers/{id}/{name}`.

In my web it shows like  `/specialoffers/15/offername`. But i want to see only `/specialoffers/offername`.  I need in controller the id of specialoffers to find it in my DB. How can i remake my router or controller action to show nice URLs?

Comment: check for the Sluggable extension here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/common_extensions.html

Comment: @malcolm names should not be used for URLs.

Comment: @xurshid29 and what else should not be used for URLs, cars makes, models, tv programs, countries, regions, cities...? Every one know that it should be slugged!

Comment: @malcolm Your "Find by name in DB" doesn't guarantee the unique results to fetch and use them for URLs.. Unique slug should be generated based on name field and queried by that slug, not by name..

Comment: @xurshid29 As I stated, any one know that. The problem is that author of question didn't know that he can query database by other fields.